# Complicated select statement which should fetch only higher levels neglecting lower levels

Tags: sql-server

How do I select a candidate who is both in State level and National level, I want to select only the higher lever(i.e here National) where the query should neglect lower levels(State).

```
+------+--+--------+-----------+
| Name |  |  Level             |
+------+--+--------+-----------+
| A    |  |   state            |
| B    |  |   State            |
| C    |  |    state           |
| A    |  |  National          |
+------+--+--------+-----------+
```

The query should fetch me A's record only once for National level and should neglect State level.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to give ranks to the highest level and then pick whichever highest..

**Schema:**

```
 CREATE TABLE #TAB( Name VARCHAR(50), LevelS VARCHAR(50) )
 INSERT INTO #TAB 
 SELECT 'A','state' 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'B','State' 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'C','state' 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'A','National'
```

Now do select like below

```
 SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN LevelS='state' THEN 2
       WHEN LevelS='National' THEN 1 END ) SNO
 ,NAME
 ,LevelS  FROM #TAB
 )A
 WHERE SNO=1
```

**Result:**

```
+-----+------+----------+
| SNO | NAME |  LevelS  |
+-----+------+----------+
|   1 | A    | National |
|   1 | B    | State    |
|   1 | C    | state    |
+-----+------+----------+
```